# ambiguous jsonp

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to make a simple request using json/jsonp for my future project and I don't know what I'm missing. I've validated my link with http://jsonlint.com/. If I replace my link with "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=earthquake&lang=en&callback=?" it works. Thank you. 
Here is my code:

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {  
                $.getJSON('http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v1/article?format=json&query=cloud+computing&facets=des_facet%2Cper_facet%2Cgeo_facet%2Cclassifiers_facet%2Corg_facet&callback&api-key=b56e8aac267230a55c6f15cfeeb2cf4f:5:67104308&callback=?', 
                function(data){
                    var html = "<ul>Hello. This is  my data.</ul>";
                    $('.nytimes').html(html);   
                });
            });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
           <p>New York Times news</p>
           <div class="nytimes">    
           </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: JSON you are receiving from both server varies from each other.

Comment: What is your problem?  What doesn't work as you expect?  Do you realize that you aren't doing anything with the `data` response?

Comment: does NY Times API return jsonp? Many API's don't. The url in example does not

Comment: @jfriend00 I know I don't do anything with the data response. This is how I figure out if there's a problem with json or I'm having trouble accessing data from arrays.
If the simple string won't display that means there's something wrong with the request.

Comment: @charlietfl I've also tried without using '&callback=?'.

Comment: So, is the problem that nothing shows up in the nytimes HTML?  You never state the problem clearly.  100% of unclear questions do not receive answers.

Comment: try jQuery.each(data,function(k,v){alert(k);alert(v)}); and see if it gives you the correct values.

Comment: the problem is it is a cross domain request and API does not return jsonp which is required. It only returns JSON. Will need to use aproxy to get the data

Comment: @techie_28 Hey, I tried iterating over 'data' with the each function like you said and no alert came up. And then I used the same code and iterated over some random array 'var arr = [ "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" ];' (outside the getJson function, of course) and it worked. So, obviously, there's something wrong with the request. If I try to access the url inside a browser, it gives me a bunch of data... so there's nothing wrong with the url either. Any other ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Yes Coz there is a problem with the json you are getting from NY Times and I am not sure what is.

Comment: @charlietfl Hi, Let me know if I made any mistake considering the proxy: I made a file proxy.php  containing the information from this page [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482786/how-to-use-proxy-with-json) and then I used that proxy in the following manner: h ttp://localhost/.../proxy.php?url=myURLAPI. And it still didn't work. PS: The http is linked together in my code.

Comment: does proxy file work in browser directly?

Comment: @techie_28, charlietfl Hey, I made the proxy file work in browser eventually, but the request still doesn't work. That's too bad. Anyway, thank you guys for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

For your reference here i attached the simple JSONP response from the Cross domains and bind the values in our UserInterface.

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: 'http://githubbadge.appspot.com/Jebasuthan',
dataType: 'jsonp',
success: function(json) {
    console.log(json);
    var result = '<h3>Name: ' + json.user.login + '</h3>' +
                 '<p>Forked Repository: ' + json.fork_repos + '</p>' +
                 '<p>Languages: ' + json.languages + '</p>' +
                 '<p>Email-Id: ' + json.user.email + '</p>' +
                 '<p>Location: ' + json.user.location + '</p>' +
                 '<p>Last Updated Date: ' + json.user.updated_at + '</p>' +
                 '<p>Blog: <a target="_blank" href='+ json.user.blog + '>' + json.user.blog + '</a></p>';
       $('#badge').append(result);
   }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Jebasuthan/9eV8s/1/)